# Centos VM serving multiple public IP: how to configure network interface?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, virtualization, nic

I have a Centos 5.6 VM (vSphere client) already responding to two different public IPs on eth0 and eth0:1 and I'm trying to add eth0:2. I copied the eth0 config file and restarted the network service. I don't understand which other steps are needed.

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:40:46:B9:00:41  
          inet addr:10.1.12.10  Bcast:10.1.12.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:163371837 errors:77 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:168210961 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1891221045 (1.7 GiB)  TX bytes:855899500 (816.2 MiB)
          Interrupt:59 Base address:0x2000 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:40:46:B9:00:41  
          inet addr:10.1.12.11  Bcast:10.1.12.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:59 Base address:0x2000 

eth0:2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:40:46:B9:00:41  
          inet addr:10.1.12.12  Bcast:10.1.12.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:59 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:188976973 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:188976973 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2015642664 (1.8 GiB)  TX bytes:2015642664 (1.8 GiB)
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 10.1.12.1
```

`route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.1.12.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.1.12.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Your IP is configured according to `ifconfig` output, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: the public IP was answering server not found. But now I finally get 404. Probably it tooks some time to react. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows that it is already configured correctly.

Server not found is usually how you would phrase a DNS error, not a connectivity error.

One thing you may need to do when you add additional IPs is restart daemons you expect to be listening on those IPs, so they bind to them.